# Search box for JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I created this code to search through my JSON data but I haven't a clue why it doesn't work. Could anyone please analyse it?

I basically need a HTML search box to search through corresponding JSON data and return it.

```js
<script>
  $('#txt-search').keyup(function(){
    var searchField;
    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) { 
      searchField = data.val();
    });
    if(searchField === '')  {
      $('#filter-records').html('');
    return;
  }
  var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  var output = '<div class="row">';
  var count = 1;
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
  if ((val.employee_salary.search(regex) != -1) || (val.employee_name.search(regex) != -1)) {
    output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';
    output += '<div class="col-md-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="'+val.profile_image+'" alt="'+ val.employee_name +'" /></div>';
    output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
    output += '<h5>' + val.employee_name + '</h5>';
    output += '<p>' + val.employee_salary + '</p>'
    output += '</div>';
    output += '</div>';
    if(count%2 == 0){
      output += '</div><div class="row">'
    }
    count++;
  }
    });
    output += '</div>';
    $('#filter-records').html(output);
        });
  </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Request JSON Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container" style="padding:50px 250px;">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="input" class="form-control input-lg" id="txt-search" placeholder="Type your search character">
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="filter-records"></div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you define "not working"? Provide what you want code to do, what it does, etc. Read about a [mcve].

Comment: jQuery is not linked in the document, maybe?

Comment: Okay I've edited it slightly. Basically I want to create an automatic search box that searches through the JSON data. I've got the easy search form part, which works fine, but no response is produced on the site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse parameters in you regex function. Here is an example that I builded and you can get an idea:

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "id":198,
      "name":"Aaron Garo",
   },
   {  
      "id":345,
      "name":"Michael Stines",
   },
   {  
      "id":545,
      "name":"Ully Heiz",
   },
   {  
      "id":678,
      "name":"Asgaf Torino",
   }
]

output = "";
$.each(data, function(key, val){
 output += "<div class='values'>";
   output += '<h5 class="value-id">' + val.id + '</h5>';
   output += '<p class="value-name">' + val.name + '</p>'
  output += "</div>";
});

$('#content').html(output);

/* SEEKER FUNCTION */
 if (!RegExp.escape) {
   RegExp.escape = function (s) {
     return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
   };
 }
 
 jQuery(function(){
  var $rows = $('.values');
  $('#seeker').keyup(function () {
    var regex =  new RegExp(RegExp.escape($.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g, ' ')), 'i')
    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
      var text = $(this).children(".value-name").text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
      return regex.test(text)
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.values{
  background: #FFFFAA;
}

.search-bar input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" id="seeker">
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: I have this code in jsfiddle too. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/mariodev64/L4vna2t3/

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. So with this do I create 2 files, one html and one css and put the javascript part in the script tags and the link the css? I'm quite the beginner. Cheers!!

Comment: Yup. Also you can create a .js file <script src="YOUROUTE"> and must works. But NOTE: You need to donwload Jquery and link it or use a CDN like I using in the example.

Comment: For some reason i really cannot get it to work - all that appears on the html file is a box - no data beneath it. Could you possible share the entire source code? I'd appreciate it so much!! thanks

Comment: My code get the data from the JSON, then print the html with that data.  regex just filter the data already printed in the html. So just hide that data that are matching. My code is complete... Pls share you current code in Jsfiddle and let me check if you doing something wrong...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/utdezs3k/    Here's my code - it seems to work in jfiddle but not on my computer (locally) for some reason ?! Thanks for the help so far!! (On my computer all that appears is an empty box - no data below!)

Comment: Did you import Jquery? the 2.2 above?. Try removing the others scripts links. Look the correct order of Jquery must be the first.